# How can I check the shader model capabilities of an adapter?

Tags: directx11, slimdx

I'm writing an application that targets Direct3D11 (through SlimDX) and shader model 5.

When I'm running it on a system that doesn't have SM5 capable hardware, I will get a NullReferenceException when trying to access the techniques in the compiled effect instance.

How can I check if the adapter is capable of this before I even attempt to use any of these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `FeatureLevel` property of the Device object. If it returns `Level_11_0` then it means that the hardware supports SM5.

Comment: Awesome. Now I also see that I can provide an array of acceptable feature levels right in the `Device.CreateWithSwapChain` call.